# How to comb a sea for enemy submarines?

Tags: freeciv

Suppose my enemy has lots of submarines, which are all being deployed in a particular sea. What is the best way to find the submarines and destroy them?

I am currently using battleships to do the job mainly because the are resistant to submarine attacks. Are there alternative methods I could use? I thought about using sacrificial transports to comb the sea, and using stealth aircraft to attack the submarines once they have been found.